# Why does the dielectric current density operator is twice its value?

Tags: electric-current, conventions, conductors, many-body, linearized-theory

In second quantization, the time-independent Hamiltonian for free fermions is written as

$$\mathcal{H}_0=\sum_\sigma\int\mathrm d^3 \mathbf r\; \Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r) \frac{\hat{P}^2}{2m } \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r) $$

In the presence of an electromagnetic field given by $A_\mu=(\phi(\mathbf r),\mathbf A (\mathbf r))$ (electric potential, magnetic vector potential), we can recover the new Hamiltonian using minimal coupling $\hat{\mathbf P}\to \hat{\mathbf P} - q\mathbf A$ and $\mathcal H\to \mathcal H_0 +q\mathbf \phi$. We have
$$\mathcal{H}_0=\sum_\sigma\int\mathrm d^3 \mathbf r\; \Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r) \left[\frac{|\hat{\mathbf P}-q\mathbf A (\mathbf r)|^2}{2m }+q\phi(\mathbf r)\right] \Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r) $$

Expanding the square and integrating by parts we have
$$\mathcal{H}_0=\sum_\sigma\int\mathrm d^3 \mathbf r\; \Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r) \left[\frac{\hat{P}^2}{2m }-q\frac{(\hat{\mathbf P}\cdot\mathbf A(\mathbf r)+\mathbf A(\mathbf r)\cdot\hat{\mathbf P})}{2m }+q^2\frac{A^2(\mathbf r)}{2m }+q\phi(\mathbf r)\right] \Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r) $$
$$=\sum_\sigma\int\mathrm d^3 \mathbf r\; \Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r) \left[\frac{\hat{P}^2}{2m }+q\phi(\mathbf r)\right] \Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r) -\sum_\sigma \int\mathrm d^3 \mathbf r\;  \hat{\mathbf J}_\sigma(\mathbf r)\cdot \mathbf A(\mathbf r)  $$
where

$$\hat{\mathbf J}_\sigma(\mathbf r)=\hat{\mathbf J}^{\rm (para)}_\sigma(\mathbf r)+\frac{\hat{\mathbf J}^{\rm (dia)}_\sigma(\mathbf r)}{2}\tag{1}\label{eq:c}$$

(NOTE THE FACTOR OF 1/2) is the electric current density. Where the paramagnetic current density is  defined as
$$\hat{\mathbf J}^{\rm (para)}_\sigma(\mathbf r)=\frac{q\hbar}{2m i}\left\{\Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r) \nabla \Psi_\sigma(\mathbf r)  - [\nabla \Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r)]\Psi_\sigma(\mathbf r) \right\}$$
and the dielectric current density as
$$\hat{\mathbf J}^{\rm (dia)}_\sigma(\mathbf r)=-q^2\frac{\mathbf A(\mathbf r)}{m}  |\Psi_\sigma(\mathbf r)|^2\;.$$

I do not understand what is the point of defining the diamagnetic current as twice the value as in Eq. \eqref{eq:c} (some books even omit the 1/2 entirely even when the expression above is exact). What is more strange to me is that it seems to have implications. When studying the linear response using Kubo's theory, there is a factor of 1/2 missing due to this definition (which could be just an issue of linearlization, but still).

Copying from H. Bruus *Many-body quantum theory in condensed matter physics*, the conductivity of Kubo's formula is given by
$$\sigma_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\mathrm iq^2}{m\omega}\langle n_\lambda(\mathbf r)\rangle_{0}\delta(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')\delta_{\alpha\beta}+\frac{\mathrm i q^2}{\omega}\Pi_{\alpha,\beta}^{R}(\mathbf r,\mathbf r',\omega)$$
where the first term should be halved if we kept the 1/2 in Eq. \eqref{eq:c}.

What's is the point of defining it as twice the value?

Comment: Looks like a fantastic question. Have you, perchance, looked at whether this has to do with the spin half g factor being double that of orbital angular momentum?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent as far as I understand spin coupling with the field is not included. I think it might be related to taking $\delta A^2=2 A\delta A $ somewhere, which seems unnatural as the expression above is exact.